# How to import a subset of a zip file into colab?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have a very big zip file in my google drive which contain several subfloders. Now, I'd like to extract only a few subfolders (not all folder into colab). Is there any  way for this?

For instance, suppose the zip file name is "MyBigFile.zip" which contain "folder1", "folder2", "folder3", "folder4", and "folder5". I only want to import and extract "folder1",and "folder4" into my google colab (and better import only 200 images from it only). How is it possible? any suggestion?

*if this is related: each folder 1-5 contains around 50000 .png files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I found something. You can use the `zipfile` module in google collab too.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

zipfile = ZipFile("Zip File Path") # MyBigFile.zip
def extract(folderName, numberOfFiles):
    files = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(folderName), zipfile.namelist()))[:numberOfFiles]
    for file in files:
        zipfile.extract(file, 'Output Folder Path')  # extractedFolder
 
extract("folder1/", 200)
zipfile.close()
```

You can remove `google.colab` code why mounting drive manually clicks on this button.

[image] [image]

After That, you can remove these two lines of code.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
# from google.colab import drive

# drive.mount('/content/drive')

zipfile = ZipFile("MyBigFile.zip")
def extract(folderName, numberOfFiles):
    files = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(folderName), zipfile.namelist()))[:numberOfFiles]
    for file in files:
        zipfile.extract(file, 'extractedFolder')

extract("folder1/", 200)
zipfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @codester_09!  that doesn't work forme. It say, no such file!
Do you think if I can select just first 200 of each folder by something like `zip.extract("folder4[:200]", "/extracted")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount your Google Drive through Colab first:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Now unzip only specific folders where you want them:

```
!unzip /path_to/MyBigFile.zip 'folder1/*' -d /path_to_unzip
```